# Where does "⿲米米産" come from?

Tags: characters

In [this](https://www.naturalexpressions.org/CKE_8.jpg) crazy English to Chinese/Kanji tattoo translation font we have the following character notated with the letter "Y" underneath.

> [image]

[Hanzismatter](http://hanzismatter.blogspot.com/2006/08/gibberish-asian-font-mystery-solved.html) notes:

> The character for "Y" is a mystery, looking something like 米米産 as one character.

There must be a method to the madness. Where does "⿲米米産" come from?

Answer (score 1):

It looked more like 林產 (from forest; forest related product: e.g. lumber). The 'y' under it is a selection code for that tattoo. Meaning you can just say "I want to have tattoo y" if you don't know how to read the  actual tattoo. Just like you can tell the waiter "I want to order number 23 on the menu" instead of stating the full name of the dish